# WP7 perform navigation from outside a PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation

I am developing a WP7 app, that consumes RESTful web services and uses login. I have a utility class for retrieving the actual data.

Whenever a certain result is received I have to perform a new login, and thus have to display the login screen to the user.

Is it possible from this utility class to force the app to navigate to some specific page? Possibly through the `App` instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, though tricky. The `App.Current` (the instance of your application) has a `RootFrame` property if cast to your `App` type, on which you can call Navigation methods.

So `(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Navigate(...)` should do the trick for you.